# ¿Cómo usar el map en un array de objetos correctamente?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, map

Necesito conseguir la data de un array de objetos, sin embargo, cuando no uso los corchetes se genera un loop infinito, y cuando los uso, este no imprime nada, si alguien sabe como implementarlo correctamente, se lo agradecería.

Aquí el código:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
       const aux: any[] = [];
       console.log('Aquí imprime');
       driverTaskData?.map((obj: any)=>{
          // aux.push(obj);
          // setDriverTaskData((aux));
          console.log('Aquí no.'); // No muestra nada
          console.log(obj); // No muestra nada
    });
  }, []);
```

Aquí un ejemplo del array:

```
[{_id: 62fe58d646052224c62e541e , patente: 4DBLU3 ,fecha: 2022-08-19 , cliente: Cliente Ejemplo , zona: Zona Ejemplo }]
[{_id: 62fe58d646052224c61f541e , patente: 4DBLU3 ,fecha: 2022-08-19 , cliente: Cliente Ejemplo , zona: Zona Ejemplo }]
[{_id: 62fe58d646052224c63b541e , patente: LVBR1C4NT3,fecha: 2022-08-19 , cliente: Cliente Ejemplo , zona: Zona Ejemplo }]
```

Necesito conseguir la data para hacer una comparación con las patentes, sin embargo no se recorrer el map sin generar el loop mencionado anteriormente.

Comment: es posible que `driverTaskData` no tenga nada ?, has verificado si antes de llegar al `map` tiene información.

Comment: esta pregunta es un duplicado de la pregunta que hiciste hace un rato y que tenía una respuesta.

Comment: el uso de map. no es esclusivo de react...  ni está asociado a use efect... es netamente un problema de javascript y de la implementacion de map que no sabes hacerla...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si, tuve que reformular el título ya que la solución que me diste era sin UseEffect, y lo necesito para poder implementarlo.

Comment: la unia diferencia es que metas el map dentro de tu scritp ... segun mi ejemplo que esperas el codigo resuelto????

Comment: @Richard Si tiene datos, e incluso el signo de pregunta después de ser invocado en el map, indica que, solo se mapeará si este tiene datos. (También te confirmo que tiene datos, porque los imprime en pantalla, a futuro tengo que lograr que solo imprima X dato en pantalla)

Comment: @Tomás el symbolo de interrogacion no valida si tienes datos; es el symbolo de encadenado opcional; lo que hara es retornar un `undefined` y evitara la salida de error al intentar iterar una variable `non-iterable`

Comment: @Tomás el problema es la implementacion de `map` que es un metodo `javascript`;  `useeffect` no tiene nada que ver con el como se manejan los datos dentro de un `map` o si llegan o no llegan, valida que `driverTaskData` Contiene datos con un `concole.log(driverTaskData);` y muestranos lo que te arroja.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ah perdón, no lo sabía, también he implementado un if en caso de ser null o undefined. Y respondiendo tu mensaje anterior, por mucho que la única diferencia sea meter el map dentro del useEffect, esa es la diferencia que hace que el código no funcione, ya que el useEffect es el problema.
Innecesario el comentario.

Comment: @Tomas por eso el titulo de tu publicacion estaba mal ... y lo que espera que ocurra dentro del map no esta asociado al metodo de afuera...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 al momento de hacer el console log me muestra 3 veces undefined y luego se renderizan las respuestas que son los array que necesito conseguir, se muestran de la siguiente manera:
`0: Object { _id: "62fe58d646052224c62e541e", initDate: "2022-08-18", asignedDate: "2022-08-19", … }` un aproximado de 6 arreglos más.

Comment: @Tomas cual prorpiedad dentro del objeto es la que necesitas evaluar y de que manera la quieres evaluar o eres feliz con que se impriman los datos en el `console.log` dentro del `map`?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Es vehículo, lo que necesito es comparar todos los vehículos y me muestre X vehículo en especifico, ejemplo:
`driverTaskData?.map((obj)=>{
if (obj.vehicle === '4DBLU3') {
   y aquí pushear las respuestas.
}
})`

Comment: la propiedad vehicle  no existe si te habras dado cuenta ... mira elobjeto de ejemplo pero el pricipio es el mismo al que aplico en mi respuesta...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ya entendí el error, dentro del useEffect, estoy usando el corchete vacío, lo que hace esto, es renderizar solo la primera vez, y cuando uso el console log, este trae undefined las primeras 3 veces (no sé por qué) y a la cuarta opción me trae datos, entonces necesito conseguir que no traiga undefined de ninguna manera.

Comment: Sin embargo si no uso el corchete, o si llamo a la variable que se modificará, ocurrirá el loop infinito.

Comment: @Tomas intenta hacer lo que coloque en mi respuesta; te estas liando mira el ejemplo al final.

Comment: me parece que el problema es que no entiendes como funciona `useEffect` y tampoco como funciona el `map`, si lo quieres usar solo para recorrer, mejor usa `foreach` , te recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). la respuesta que ya te dieron es muy clara y con eso deberías poder resolver tu problema.

Comment: otra cosa, es que no veo donde utilizas `aux` o su razón de ser y en el código que muestras no veo por que genere un loop infinito

Answer (score 1):

En un escenario de array de objetos tendriamos los siguiente datos de ejemplo:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    prop1: 'one',
    prop2: true,
    prop3: 'three',
  },
  {
    prop1: 'one',
    prop2: false,
    prop3: 'three',
  },
];

console.log(arr)
```

Para implementar `.map()` y acceder a las propiedades de un objeto dentro del callbak tendrias que implementar algo similar a esto:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    prop1: 'one',
    prop2: true,
    prop3: 'three',
  },
  {
    prop1: 'one',
    prop2: false,
    prop3: 'three',
  },
];

arr.map((value,key) => {
  if(value.prop2 == true){
    console.log('i find a valid true on key: '+key);
  }

  console.log(value,key);
})
```

Como podras observas en callback he ejecutado una validacion, que me permite mostrar un texto para una circunstacia especifica.

***En tu caso el Metodo quedaria de la siguiente forma:***

```js
//ejemplo de los dato en driverTaskData
const driverTaskData = [
{_id: '62fe58d646052224c62e541e' , patente: '4DBLU3' ,fecha: '2022-08-19' , cliente: 'Cliente Ejemplo' , zona: 'Zona Ejemplo' },
{_id: '62fe58d646052224c61f541e' , patente: '4DBLU3' ,fecha: '2022-08-19' , cliente: 'Cliente Ejemplo' , zona: 'Zona Ejemplo' },
{_id: '62fe58d646052224c63b541e' , patente: 'LVBR1C4NT3',fecha: '2022-08-19' , cliente: 'Cliente Ejemplo' , zona: 'Zona Ejemplo' }
];


//iterrar el array driverTaskData
driverTaskData.map((value,key) => {
      console.log(value,key);
      console.log(value.patente);

});
```

entonces este map es el que deberias de colocar y adaptar a tu metodo `useEffect`.